# Как открыть VS code в папке?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Нажимаю сочетание клавиш <kbd>shift</kbd> + ПКМ, у меня только "Открыть окно команд". Нужно открыть VS code. [image: Нужен такой результат]

[image: Моя проблема]

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант, это переустановить VS Code и при установке отметить галочками "Add path to exlorer". Второй вариант это создать текстовый файл, который потом переименовать в любое_название.reg со следующим содержанием (Внимание, это сработает, только при условии, что Vs Code установлен в папку по умолчанию!):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\VSCode]
@=hex(2):4f,00,70,00,65,00,6e,00,20,00,77,00,69,00,74,00,68,00,20,00,43,00,26,\
  00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,00,00
"Icon"=hex(2):43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
  00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,5c,00,4d,00,69,00,63,00,72,00,6f,00,73,00,\
  6f,00,66,00,74,00,20,00,56,00,53,00,20,00,43,00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,5c,00,43,\
  00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\VSCode\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
  00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,5c,00,4d,00,69,00,63,00,72,00,6f,00,73,00,\
  6f,00,66,00,74,00,20,00,56,00,53,00,20,00,43,00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,5c,00,43,\
  00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,\
  22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\VSCode]
@=hex(2):4f,00,70,00,65,00,6e,00,20,00,77,00,69,00,74,00,68,00,20,00,43,00,26,\
  00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,00,00
"Icon"=hex(2):43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
  00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,5c,00,4d,00,69,00,63,00,72,00,6f,00,73,00,\
  6f,00,66,00,74,00,20,00,56,00,53,00,20,00,43,00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,5c,00,43,\
  00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\VSCode\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
  00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,5c,00,4d,00,69,00,63,00,72,00,6f,00,73,00,\
  6f,00,66,00,74,00,20,00,56,00,53,00,20,00,43,00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,5c,00,43,\
  00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,56,00,\
  22,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\VSCode]
@=hex(2):4f,00,70,00,65,00,6e,00,20,00,77,00,69,00,74,00,68,00,20,00,43,00,26,\
  00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,00,00
"Icon"=hex(2):43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
  00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,5c,00,4d,00,69,00,63,00,72,00,6f,00,73,00,\
  6f,00,66,00,74,00,20,00,56,00,53,00,20,00,43,00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,5c,00,43,\
  00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\VSCode\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
  00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,5c,00,4d,00,69,00,63,00,72,00,6f,00,73,00,\
  6f,00,66,00,74,00,20,00,56,00,53,00,20,00,43,00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,5c,00,43,\
  00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,56,00,\
  22,00,00,00
```

Answer (score 0):

Если у кого установленно не в дефолтную папку, просто по реестру пройдитесь и измените все пути (можно только в одной папке, но лучше везде).

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо».  Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [проголосовать за вопросы и ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), которые сочтёте полезными. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/778889)